# Spring Data MongoDB compare two document field

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I want to query documents based on the following criteria: foo.a != foo.b

Example:

```
db.foo.insert({a: "1", b: "1"});
db.foo.insert({a: "2", b: "2"});
db.foo.insert({a: "1", b: "2"});
```

Following mongo query:

```
db.foo.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
                  a: 1,
                  b: 1,
                  aNeB: {$ne:["$a","$b"]}
                }
    },
    {
      $match : { aNeB: true }
    }
  ]
);
```

gives me: {a: "1", b: "2"}

The problem is that i can't create aNeB projection field:

Code template:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                project("a", "b")
                .andExpression("$ne:['$a','$b']").as("aNeB"),
                match(Criteria.where("aNeB").is(true)),
                group().count().as("count")
        );
```

How can i do this using Spring Data MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Since the method `andExpression` takes an [spEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) as input, you would need to modify it to:

`.andExpression("a!=b").as("aNeB")`..